# Trying to install Webmin on Ubuntu 18.04 - missing apt-show-versions

Tags: 18.04, webmin, source-packages

I've tried following the following commands to install Webmin on my home server:

```
sudo apt install python apt-show-versions libapt-pkg-perl libauthen-pam-perl libio-pty-perl libnet-ssleay-perl
```

But it cannot locate the apt-show-versions package. Do I have to add something to sources.list?

I've managed to find [this webpage](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/bionic/+source/apt-show-versions) and downloaded it onto my server.

I've cd'ed into the directory but how do I install it? It's the final requirement so I can execute the following command:

```
sudo apt install webmin
```